# Beautiful Soup scrape Multiple URLs with Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, csv, url, beautifulsoup, scrape

Below code works fine, but I need to scrape multiple URLs and I don't know really how...

Would be nice also if possible to scrape the urls from a CSV file...

Basically I'm trying to get a redirect link from a search link

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.tennis-point.fr/index.php?stoken=737F2976&lang=1&cl=search&searchparam=E705Y-0193"

# Getting the webpage, creating a Response object.
response = requests.get(url)

# Extracting the source code of the page.
data = response.text

# Passing the source code to BeautifulSoup to create a BeautifulSoup object for it.
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

# Extracting all the <a> tags into a list.
tags = soup.find("div", {"class": "productsPicture"}).findAll("a")

# Extracting URLs from the attribute href in the <a> tags.
for tag in tags:
    print(tag.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will fetch all urls (`href`):

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.tennis-point.fr/index.php?stoken=737F2976&lang=1&cl=search&searchparam=E705Y-0193"

# Getting the webpage, creating a Response object.
response = requests.get(url)

# Extracting the source code of the page.
data = response.text

# Passing the source code to BeautifulSoup to create a BeautifulSoup object for it.
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
# print soup
urls =[ item.get("href") for item in soup.find_all("a")]
print(urls)
```

## output:

```
[u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/frais-d-expedition-et-de-livraison/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/garantie-satisfait-ou-rembourse/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/protection-des-donnees/', u'tel:+33(0)368331651', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/index.php?cl=account&', u'#loginBox', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/index.php?cl=register&', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/index.php?cl=account&', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/index.php?cl=account_order&', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/index.php?cl=account_user&', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/index.php?cl=newsletter&', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/aide-services/', u'#', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/index.php?cl=account_wishlist&', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/index.php?cl=basket&', u'#', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/index.php?cl=basket&', u'#', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/raquettes-de-tennis/', u'/raquettes-de-tennis/enfants/', u'/raquettes-de-tennis/unisex/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/raquettes-de-tennis/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/raquettes-de-tennis-raquettes-de-competition/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/raquettes-de-tennis-raquettes-polyvalentes/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/raquettes-de-tennis-raquettes-confort/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/raquettes-de-tennis-raquettes-enfants/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/raquettes-de-tennis-raquettes-d-occasion/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/raquettes-de-tennis-lots-de-raquettes/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/raquettes-de-tennis-accessoires-raquettes/', u'/raquettes-de-tennis/babolat/', u'/raquettes-de-tennis/dunlop/', u'/raquettes-de-tennis/head/', u'/raquettes-de-tennis/kirschbaum/', u'/raquettes-de-tennis/pacific/', u'/raquettes-de-tennis/prince/', u'/raquettes-de-tennis/prokennex/', u'/raquettes-de-tennis/tecnifibre/', u'/raquettes-de-tennis/tennis-point/', u'/raquettes-de-tennis/topspin/', u'/raquettes-de-tennis/tourna/', u'/raquettes-de-tennis/voelkl/', u'/raquettes-de-tennis/wilson/', u'/raquettes-de-tennis/yonex/', u'/marques/raquettes-de-tennis/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/vetements-de-tennis/', u'/vetements-de-tennis/enfants/', u'/vetements-de-tennis/femmes/', u'/vetements-de-tennis/filles/', u'/vetements-de-tennis/garcons/', u'/vetements-de-tennis/hommes/', u'/vetements-de-tennis/unisex/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/vetements-de-tennis/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/vetements-de-tennis-robes/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/vetements-de-tennis-shirts-tops/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/vetements-de-tennis-jupes/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/vetements-de-tennis-vestes/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/vetements-de-tennis-sweats-hoodies/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/vetements-de-tennis-shorts/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/vetements-de-tennis-pantalons/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/vetements-de-tennis-survetements/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/vetements-de-tennis-compression/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/vetements-de-tennis-chaussettes/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/vetements-de-tennis-sous-vetements/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/vetements-de-tennis-accessoires/', u'/vetements-de-tennis/adidas/', u'/vetements-de-tennis/asics/', u'/vetements-de-tennis/babolat/', u'/vetements-de-tennis/bidi-badu/', u'/vetements-de-tennis/bidi-badu-by-kilian-kerner/', u'/vetements-de-tennis/bjoern-borg/', u'/vetements-de-tennis/dunlop/', u'/vetements-de-tennis/erima/', u'/vetements-de-tennis/fila/', u'/vetements-de-tennis/head/', u'/vetements-de-tennis/hydrogen/', u'/vetements-de-tennis/lacoste/', u'/vetements-de-tennis/limited-sports/', u'/vetements-de-tennis/lotto/', u'/vetements-de-tennis/nike/', u'/vetements-de-tennis/puma/', u'/vetements-de-tennis/reebok/', u'/vetements-de-tennis/sergio-tacchini/', u'/vetements-de-tennis/tennis-point/', u'/vetements-de-tennis/tonic/', u'/vetements-de-tennis/under-armour/', u'/vetements-de-tennis/wilson/', u'/vetements-de-tennis/yonex/', u'/marques/vetements-de-tennis/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/chaussures-de-tennis/', u'/chaussures-de-tennis/enfants/', u'/chaussures-de-tennis/femmes/', u'/chaussures-de-tennis/hommes/', u'/chaussures-de-tennis/unisex/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/chaussures-de-tennis/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/chaussures-de-tennis-toutes-surfaces/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/chaussures-de-tennis-terre-battue/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/chaussures-de-tennis-moquette/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/chaussures-de-tennis-loisir/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/chaussures-de-tennis-accessoires-chaussures/', u'/chaussures-de-tennis/adidas/', u'/chaussures-de-tennis/asics/', u'/chaussures-de-tennis/babolat/', u'/chaussures-de-tennis/erdal/', u'/chaussures-de-tennis/head/', u'/chaussures-de-tennis/ivybands/', u'/chaussures-de-tennis/k-swiss/', u'/chaussures-de-tennis/lotto/', u'/chaussures-de-tennis/mizuno/', u'/chaussures-de-tennis/new-balance/', u'/chaussures-de-tennis/nike/', u'/chaussures-de-tennis/prince/', u'/chaussures-de-tennis/pro-touch/', u'/chaussures-de-tennis/salomon/', u'/chaussures-de-tennis/under-armour/', u'/chaussures-de-tennis/wilson/', u'/chaussures-de-tennis/yonex/', u'/marques/chaussures-de-tennis/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/sacs-de-tennis/', u'/sacs-de-tennis/enfants/', u'/sacs-de-tennis/femmes/', u'/sacs-de-tennis/hommes/', u'/sacs-de-tennis/unisex/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/sacs-de-tennis/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/sacs-de-tennis-sacs-a-raquettes/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/sacs-de-tennis-sacs-a-dos/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/sacs-de-tennis-sacs-de-sport/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/sacs-de-tennis-autres-sacs/', u'/sacs-de-tennis/adidas/', u'/sacs-de-tennis/asics/', u'/sacs-de-tennis/babolat/', u'/sacs-de-tennis/bidi-badu/', u'/sacs-de-tennis/dunlop/', u'/sacs-de-tennis/head/', u'/sacs-de-tennis/lacoste/', u'/sacs-de-tennis/nike/', u'/sacs-de-tennis/prince/', u'/sacs-de-tennis/tecnifibre/', u'/sacs-de-tennis/tennis-point/', u'/sacs-de-tennis/topspin/', u'/sacs-de-tennis/under-armour/', u'/sacs-de-tennis/wilson/', u'/sacs-de-tennis/yonex/', u'/marques/sacs-de-tennis/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/balles-de-tennis/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/balles-de-tennis/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/balles-de-tennis-balles-de-competition/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/balles-de-tennis-balles-d-entrainement/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/balles-de-tennis-balles-geantes/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/balles-de-tennis-balles-intermediaires/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/balles-de-tennis-balles-lots-de-balles/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/balles-de-tennis-balles-officielles-itf/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/balles-de-tennis-balles-sans-pression/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/balles-de-tennis-lots-de-balles/', u'/balles-de-tennis/babolat/', u'/balles-de-tennis/balls-unlimited/', u'/balles-de-tennis/dunlop/', u'/balles-de-tennis/head/', u'/balles-de-tennis/tennis-point/', u'/balles-de-tennis/tretorn/', u'/balles-de-tennis/wilson/', u'/marques/balles-de-tennis/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/cordages-de-tennis/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/cordages-de-tennis/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/cordages-de-tennis-bobines-cordage/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/cordages-de-tennis-cordages-en-set/', u'/cordages-de-tennis/babolat/', u'/cordages-de-tennis/dunlop/', u'/cordages-de-tennis/gamma/', u'/cordages-de-tennis/head/', u'/cordages-de-tennis/isospeed/', u'/cordages-de-tennis/kirschbaum/', u'/cordages-de-tennis/luxilon/', u'/cordages-de-tennis/msv/', u'/cordages-de-tennis/pacific/', u'/cordages-de-tennis/polyfibre/', u'/cordages-de-tennis/prince/', u'/cordages-de-tennis/signum-pro/', u'/cordages-de-tennis/solinco/', u'/cordages-de-tennis/tecnifibre/', u'/cordages-de-tennis/tennis-point/', u'/cordages-de-tennis/topspin/', u'/cordages-de-tennis/tourna/', u'/cordages-de-tennis/weiss-cannon/', u'/cordages-de-tennis/wilson/', u'/cordages-de-tennis/yonex/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/autres/', u'/autres/femmes/', u'/autres/unisex/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/autres/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/autres-grips-de-tennis/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/autres-padel/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/autres-squash/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/autres-badminton/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/autres-accessoires-pour-entraineurs/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/autres-equipement-court-de-tennis/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/autres-accessoires/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/autres-bons-d-achat/', u'/autres/adidas/', u'/autres/babolat/', u'/autres/bidi-badu/', u'/autres/dunlop/', u'/autres/gamma/', u'/autres/head/', u'/autres/nike/', u'/autres/pacific/', u'/autres/prince/', u'/autres/rehband/', u'/autres/schildkroet-fitness/', u'/autres/sergio-tacchini/', u'/autres/tecnifibre/', u'/autres/tegra/', u'/autres/tomtom/', u'/autres/toolz/', u'/autres/topspin/', u'/autres/tourna/', u'/autres/tretorn/', u'/autres/universal-sport/', u'/autres/wilson/', u'/marques/autres/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/marques/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/nike/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/adidas/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/wilson/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/head/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/babolat/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/asics/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/bidi-badu/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/k-swiss/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/babolat/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/head/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/toolz/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/wilson/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/2xu/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/70love/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/adidas/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/asics/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/atp/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/balls-unlimited/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/bidi-badu/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/bidi-badu-by-kilian-kerner/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/bjoern-borg/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/boot-doc/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/cep/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/currex/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/diadora/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/dunlop/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/enebe/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/energetics/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/erdal/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/erima/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/falke/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/fila/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/fitbit/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/gamma/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/garmin/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/hydrogen/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/isospeed/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/ivybands/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/k-swiss/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/kirschbaum/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/lacoste/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/limited-sports/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/lobster/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/lotto/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/luxilon/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/mikros/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/mizuno/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/msv/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/nasara/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/new-balance/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/nike/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/pacific/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/polyfibre/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/prince/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/pro-touch/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/prokennex/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/puma/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/reebok/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/rehband/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/salomon/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/schildkroet-fitness/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/sergio-tacchini/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/signum-pro/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/solinco/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/sports-tutor/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/sportsmed/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/syneo/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/talbot/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/tecnifibre/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/tegra/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/tennis-point/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/tomtom/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/tonic/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/topspin/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/tourna/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/tretorn/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/tri-tennis/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/under-armour/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/universal-sport/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/voelkl/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/weiss-cannon/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/x-bionic/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/x-socks/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/yonex/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/professionnels/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/roger-federer/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/serena-williams/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/rafael-nadal/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/victoria-azarenka/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/andy-murray/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/maria-sharapova/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/novak-djokovic/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/angelique-kerber/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/agnieszka-radwanska/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/alexander-zverev/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/alize-cornet/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/andrea-petkovic/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/andy-murray/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/angelique-kerber/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/benoit-paire/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/bernard-tomic/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/borna-coric/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/carina-witthoeft/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/caroline-garcia/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/caroline-wozniacki/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/coco-vandeweghe/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/david-ferrer/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/david-goffin/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/dominic-thiem/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/dominika-cibulkova/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/elena-vesnina/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/eugenie-bouchard/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/fabio-fognini/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/feliciano-lopez/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/fernando-verdasco/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/florian-mayer/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/frances-tiafoe/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/gael-monfils/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/garbine-muguruza/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/gilles-muller/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/gilles-simon/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/grigor-dimitrov/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/ivo-karlovic/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/jack-sock/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/jan-lennard-struff/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/jelena-ostapenko/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/jo-wilfried-tsonga/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/johanna-konta/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/juan-martin-del-potro/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/julia-goerges/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/karolina-pliskova/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/kei-nishikori/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/kevin-anderson/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/kiki-bertens/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/kristina-mladenovic/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/lucas-pouille/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/lucie-afarova/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/magdalena-rybarikova/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/marcos-baghdatis/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/maria-sharapova/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/marin-cilic/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/martin-klizan/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/milos-raonic/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/mischa-zverev/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/mona-barthel/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/nick-kyrgios/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/novak-djokovic/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/pablo-cuevas/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/petra-kvitova/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/philipp-kohlschreiber/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/rafael-nadal/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/richard-gasquet/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/roberto-bautista-agut/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/roger-federer/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/samantha-stosur/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/serena-williams/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/simona-halep/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/sloane-stephens/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/stan-wawrinka/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/tomas-berdych/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/victoria-azarenka/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/viktor-troicki/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/yulia-putintseva/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/promos/', u'/promos/enfants/', u'/promos/femmes/', u'/promos/filles/', u'/promos/garcons/', u'/promos/hommes/', u'/promos/unisex/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/promos/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/promos-raquettes-de-tennis/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/promos-vetements-de-tennis/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/promos-chaussures-de-tennis/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/promos-sacs-de-tennis/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/promos-balles-de-tennis/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/promos-cordages-de-tennis/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/promos-grips/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/promos-autres/', u'/promos/2xu/', u'/promos/70love/', u'/promos/adidas/', u'/promos/asics/', u'/promos/atp/', u'/promos/babolat/', u'/promos/bidi-badu/', u'/promos/bidi-badu-by-kilian-kerner/', u'/promos/bjoern-borg/', u'/promos/cep/', u'/promos/diadora/', u'/promos/dunlop/', u'/promos/enebe/', u'/promos/erima/', u'/promos/falke/', u'/promos/fila/', u'/promos/gamma/', u'/promos/head/', u'/promos/hydrogen/', u'/promos/isospeed/', u'/promos/k-swiss/', u'/promos/lacoste/', u'/promos/limited-sports/', u'/marques/promos/', u'javascript:history.back()', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/', u'/chaussures-de-tennis/', None, u'/39-5/?searchparam=E705Y-0193', u'/40/?searchparam=E705Y-0193', u'/40-5/?searchparam=E705Y-0193', u'/41-5/?searchparam=E705Y-0193', u'/42-5/?searchparam=E705Y-0193', u'/42/?searchparam=E705Y-0193', u'/43-5/?searchparam=E705Y-0193', u'/44/?searchparam=E705Y-0193', u'/44-5/?searchparam=E705Y-0193', u'/45/?searchparam=E705Y-0193', u'/46-5/?searchparam=E705Y-0193', u'/46/?searchparam=E705Y-0193', u'/47/?searchparam=E705Y-0193', u'/49/?searchparam=E705Y-0193', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/?cl=search&searchparam=E705Y-0193&searchparam=E705Y-0193', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/?cl=search&searchparam=E705Y-0193&searchparam=E705Y-0193&listorderby=oxpos&listorder=desc', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/?cl=search&searchparam=E705Y-0193&searchparam=E705Y-0193&listorderby=tc_first_stock_date&listorder=desc', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/?cl=search&searchparam=E705Y-0193&searchparam=E705Y-0193&listorderby=oxprice&listorder=asc', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/?cl=search&searchparam=E705Y-0193&searchparam=E705Y-0193&listorderby=oxprice&listorder=desc', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/?cl=search&searchparam=E705Y-0193&searchparam=E705Y-0193&listorderby=_value_uvp&listorder=desc', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/?cl=search&searchparam=E705Y-0193&searchparam=E705Y-0193&listorderby=oxrating&listorder=desc', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/asics-gel-game-6-02013802643000.html', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/asics-gel-game-6-02013802643000.html', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/avantage-tennis-point/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/frais-d-expedition-et-de-livraison/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/garantie-satisfait-ou-rembourse/', u'tel:+33 (0) 3 68 33 16 51', u'mailto:info@tennis-point.fr', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/contact/', u'https://www.trustedshops.com/bewertung/info_X06E4EA65E7491784124112051AF688AD.html', u'https://www.facebook.com/tennispoint.fr/', u'https://www.instagram.com/tennis_point_official/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/mentions-legales/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/conditions-generales/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/retractation-formulaire-de-retractation/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/protection-des-donnees/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/garantie-satisfait-ou-rembourse/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/aide-services/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/service-retour/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/affiliate/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/connexionentraineurs/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/modes-de-paiement/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/frais-d-expedition-et-de-livraison/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/retour-reclamation/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/index.php?cl=account&', u'https://www.tennis-point.de', u'https://www.tennis-point.com', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr', u'https://www.tennis-point.it', u'https://www.tennis-point.es', u'https://www.tennis-point.nl', u'https://www.tennis-point.be', u'https://www.tennis-point.cz', u'https://www.tennis-point.sk', u'https://www.tennis-point.ch', u'https://www.tennis-point.at', u'https://www.tennis-point.co.uk', u'https://www.tennis-point.dk', u'https://www.tennis-point.se', u'/nike/', u'/adidas/', u'/wilson/', u'/babolat/', u'/head/', u'/asics/', u'/dunlop/', u'/tennis-point/', u'/under-armour/', u'/k-swiss/', u'/yonex/', u'/prince/', u'/lacoste/', u'/lotto/', u'/tretorn/', u'/limited-sports/', u'/fila/', u'/bjoern-borg/', u'/raquettes-de-tennis/', u'/vetements-de-tennis/', u'/chaussures-de-tennis/', u'/sacs-de-tennis/', u'/balles-de-tennis/', u'/cordages-de-tennis/', u'/marques/', u'/professionnels/', u'/promos/', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/index.php?cl=forgotpwd&', u'https://www.tennis-point.fr/index.php?cl=register&']
```

Comment: Hi Rachit,that I know how to do it, I was wondering how I can scrape multiple urls not just one, as shown on in my code above. Something like urls = ['http://www.url1.com', 'http://www.url2.com', 
 'http://www.url3.com'] . But thank you for you time though !

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to scrap each of your URLs individually. If you want to scrape the same stuff from each page, a simple loop will suffice.

```
urls = ['url1','url2','url3']
for u in urls:
    response = requests.get(u)
    data = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')
    #
    #Scraping Code
    #
```

Comment: Hi Charlie, sorry didn't helped :( can you provide a full code ? maybe I'm missing something :( Also, what do u think about CSV option ?